# Ionic - Scroll to elements of a page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a terms page in which included links on the top. The purpose of these links is to scroll to page element that belongs to.

Is there any way to do this dynamically from the component?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Eventually there is a [scrollTo() method](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/content/Content/#scrollTo) that give you the ability to scroll to any coordinates you want.

In my component I have use the method like this:

```
export class TermsComponent {
    @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

    scrollTo(elementId: string) {
        let y = document.getElementById(elementId).offsetTop;
        this.content.scrollTo(0, y);
    }

}
```

`scrollTo()` get an argument with the id of the element you want to scroll to.

In my template:

```
<a (click)="scrollTo('section1')">Section 1</a>
<p id="section1"><b>1. The first element you want to scroll</b></p>
```

Ionic 4 ([Muhammad Tahir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2074962/muhammad-tahir)):

Use `this.content.scrollToPoint(0, y);`

Comment: in ionic 4. Use 
this.content.scrollToPoint(0, y);

Comment: Is it possible to use `ViewChild` instead of `getElementById`? Conflicting id's might be a nasty thing in a larger application which I would like to avoid by not using id's at all. But when I tried `ViewChild` and `element.nativeElement.offsetTop`, the scroll amount was incorrect.